# passing record / class labels as parameters

Tags: parameters, f#, parameter-passing, label

Is it possible to pass a record or class label as a parameter to a function?

I am not sure that is the best way to describe my question / problem, perhaps it is better illustrated by this example.

Here I have hardcoded a function to filter the list where `i.a` is equal to `v` . Is it possible to make the `i.a` passable as well?

example code:

```
type myrecord =
    {
    a : int;
    b : float
    }
```

'

```
   let abclist = [{ a = 1; b = 2.}; { a = 11; b = 22.}
```

'

```
let filter1 (recordList : List<myrecord>) v =
     recordList |> List.filter (fun i -> i.a = v)
```

how can I make the `i.a` passable? so that, for example,  I can call the function and filter for `i.b` instead?

I'm sure it's super simple (like most things in f#) but I can't beat the type error message!

Cheers,

dusiod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do, but here are some options:

```
 filter1 (recordList |> List.map (fun t -> t.b)) v
```

or changing the declaration to

```
filter1 (recordList: List<myrecord>) (v:'t) (f:myrecord -> 't) = 
    recordList |> List.filter (fun i -> (f i) = v)
```

where `f` is something like `fun t -> t.b`

A simpler version of your existing function could be

```
recordList |> List.filter (function |{a=A} -> A=v)
```

Comment: Even shorter, save 6 chars ;) -> recordList |> List.filter (fun {a=A} -> A=v)

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer - the second code example achieves what I was trying to do. Need to read up on generic type deceleration! Cheers, dusiod.